# $fillable laravel

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, controller, model

buen dia

tengo un formulario dinamico los label y el name del input se cargan dependiendo de una base de datos   la cual dependiento de la linea me trae el name de inpunt como una lista lo que quiero hacer es guardar estos input en mi base de datos ya tengo los modelos creados y demas uso para guardar create el cual recoge la informacion como array  pero este tipo de guardado se le debe especificar los valores que se pueden subir masivamente segun la documentacion hay alguna forma que en le modelo pueda especificarle que quiero todo lo que este en la pagina masivo o de quitarlo o de traer desde la base de datos estos valores  ??

**modelo**

```
class headform extends Model
```

{
use HasFactory;

```
protected $table="pruebas";
protected $fillable = [
 'maquina'
,'codigo_formulario'
,' producto_tamaño'
,'hora_inicio'
,'hora_final'
,'fecha_empaque  ' 
,'fecha_vencimiento'
,'lote'
,'inspecion_filtros'
,'operario'
,'ingeniero'
,'observaciones'
```

];
}

este modelo no tiene los campos que se cargan desde la base de datos

** blade**
haci traigo los label y name de la base de datos

```
<input class="datos" type="number" name="{{$pro->nombre_proceso}}" value=""></td>
```

en resumen hay alguna forma de guardar los datos sin tener que especificar en el modelo $fillable=[?];

gracias de antemano

Comment: $fillable solo es necesario si usas el método `create` en otro caso no, por otro lado ¿puedes redactar mejor tu pregunat por favor?

Comment: si lo se pero el metodo save toca especificarle los campos lo que quiero es recogerlos desde la base de datos para poder guardarlos